# Bootstrap Carousel Only loads one picture

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Im starting my first project and trying to incorporate a carousel but for some reason the carousel wont load the other pictures and when i try to click on the circles on the bottom to view the other pictures it stays only on the first. I followed instructions to the tee and have looked over it for a while and still cant seem to get it to work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <title>Agapé Dance Company ∞</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>


<!--Carousel section -->
            <div id="#myCarousel" class="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="agape performing" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>  
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="agape performing" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>  
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="agape performing" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>  
                </div>  
            </div>          

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you check your console to see if you have any errors?